# How to keep DRY a Ajax web forms solution

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, templating

At the moment we have a solution which is Web forms ASP.Net 4.0. We do a number of things such as using web methods and services either calling them using the standard web forms way or sometimes to reduce the footprint directly calling them with jQuery ajax posts and gets.

We are looking to improve the way we work but we have heavy constricts regarding how the solution is at the moment and not being able to completely rewrite it.

Updating the page using Ajaxs for data, forms and for example pulling "the next 20" items and displaying them on the page it what I would like to heavily stream line.

Using template's due as PURE and jQuery Templates is fantastic way to produce fast calls back and forth between the servers but results in having two copies of the html. (the template for the jQuery and the code in the actual first render of the page)

We have thought about possible producing a empty template and then always populating it via json data we post down to the server but I feel this isn't how things should be done...

can anyone reckoned the best way we can do this without having two copies of our 'template' (e.g. a row of a table)

Answer (score 0):

You mean you have a template in asp and the same template in javascript, but you'd rather just have 1 or the other?

I think that is really subjective. It is always different based on use case. That being said I'd do it by modifying my views and templates. My views (non-js) would simply have containers for that dynamic content. In other words I'd never load the dynamic portions of content into the views initially. Rather, on page load I would simply load up the template and the json that fills it in.

If you think about it that's 2 more requests, but it makes your life easier. The user also is able to see something on the page sooner.

This is one of those questions that really depends on what you are doing. There are trade-offs to be analyzed with every solution.

Comment: yes as you said. I would rather have one... I always thought bad of making extra requests but maybe I shouldn't have.. and multiple requests for one page isn't such a issue

Comment: I mean twitter and facebook do it all day long. Check them out when your internet connection is being terrible. I don't know about twitter, but those facebook guys are pretty clever :).